# Subset data.table into several data.tables by value in column

Tags: r, data.table, subset

I have the following subset from a larger data.table, I need to break it up into several data.tables that have identical date values in the "add" column:

```
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species        add
1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa 2012-01-04
2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa 2012-01-04
3:          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa 2012-01-05
4:          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa 2012-01-05
5:          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa 2012-01-06
6:          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa 2012-01-06
```

the goal is for it to consist of multiple data.tables (one data.table for each unique date in "add") that look like like this: (preferably named "Jan042012", "Jan052012", "Jan062012")

```
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species        add
1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa 2012-01-04
2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa 2012-01-04
```

```
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species        add
1:          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa 2012-01-05
2:          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa 2012-01-05
```

```
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species        add
1:          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa 2012-01-06
2:          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa 2012-01-06
```

Comment: `split(df, df$add)`?